# User mongod does not exist when trying to run Mongod as a service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run Mongod as a service in a remote server by executing the following command:

`sudo service mongod start`

However, I receive this message:

`Starting mongod: runuser: user mongod does not exist
                                                           [FAILED]`

When I start MongoDB in the foreground using `sudo mongod` it works ok.

Please can anyone suggest what I need to do to resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

error says the system user `mongod`  does not exist however if you installed using the mongo package in below link it will automatically get created ... you can manually create that id however its not a normal unix id and its powers must mesh with config and logging so be ware

what version OS are you on ?  (this is a very OS specific question)

if on a debian based (ubuntu, etc...) see docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

after creating that id (or better yet adhere to that link) then here is how to launch from a systemd based box assuming you have setup its startup script (see details in link)

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod

sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

Above works however if you are Docker savvy it's extremely easy to spin up a mongo container ... benefit is above grizzly details disappear replaced by a one-liner ...  I'm in a bar will give details tomorrow

Comment: Thank you, Scott, for your answer. I was able to get MongoDB to run in the background using this command:
`mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log`
I will still read up on the doc you sent a link for as I am interested to learn if that is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you install mongo using compressed file instead of package the user mongod is not created.
This problem is solved by changing the two fields in config file at /etc/init.d/mongod

```
MONGO_USER=mongod
MONGO_GROUP=mongod
```

change these fields to root.

```
./mongod start
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
Starting mongod:                                           [  OK  ]
```